# What is the song in episode 13 when Levi shows up after Eren seals the breached gate?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

What's the song that plays on *Attack on Titan* season 1 episode 13, when Levi shows up to save the remainder of the elite force after Eren seals the breached gate?

Comment: Cross-posted on [Quora](https://qr.ae/TWI68d) with answer: 進撃st-hrn-gt-pf20130629巨人 (need someone to confirm which one is correct)

Answer (score 0):

It’s “[巨♀~9地区](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/%E5%B7%A8%E2%99%80%7E9%E5%9C%B0%E5%8C%BA)” in Japanese. It means “Female Titan Extermination” ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/0Vs2beUh3k8?t=129)) and in English it’s “Titan♀-9chiku” ([Apple Music](https://itunes.apple.com/au/album//661050312)).

I used the [AHA Music](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aha-music-music-identifie/dpacanjfikmhoddligfbehkpomnbgblf?hl=en) Chrome extension to identify it.